# Usefulness of studying fundamentals of logic and cognition

Tags: book-recommendation, philosophy

Usual mathematicians and phyisicists do not really care seriously about the validity of logic itself, the true entity of concepts such as sets, functions, particles, or effectiveness of our cognitive ability. However these kinds of things always make me feel uncomfortable; not settling them perfectly and cleanly seem to ignore the importance of the basis on which a building stands....

So I have two questions.

1. What exactly is the usefulness of delving into those fundamental issues regarding our cognition and thinking?
2. Are there introductory books on these issues to read? Could anyone recommend me some?

Comment: How many mathematicians have you been around ... I question your hypothesis based on 10 years around the minds of the GIMPS forum.

Comment: I include physicists as well.

Comment: If there are those people outside my sight, could you introduce them?

Comment: most rules in lower math of everyday life have logic inference rule equivalents. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference

Comment: You're talking about ["foundations of mathematics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics), and there are plenty of people that are interested in this area (although only a small percentage of mathematicians specialize in it.)

Comment: OEIS editor Charles R Greathouse the fourth for 1. R D Silvermann though he was battling cancer at last check. etc. I bet you don't know there's a difference between sound and valid.

Comment: Yes I certainly know the difference....